# Invoking a function over a sequence of CRTP derived instances

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, crtp

Suppose I have a templated function that takes a generic parameter that sticks to the concept/interface of its CRTP base class like

```
template <typename Parser_T>
void print(Parser_T&& parser)
```

Now I want to iterate over a sequence of those CRTP derived instances to invoke this function. The best I came up was to use `std::variant` of all known sub classes, and use `std::visit` combined with a lambda to invoke the templated function.

Is there an easier way to do this, especially getting rid of the lambda? I don't have to store the instances homogeneous, some kind of a template trick list would be fine. But I have to able to specify the order, i.e. the instance sequence of course to invoke.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

template <class T>
struct parser_base
{
    std::string parse()
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->parse_impl();
    }
};

struct parser_a : parser_base<parser_a>
{
    std::string parse_impl() {
        return "A\n";
    }

};

struct parser_b : parser_base<parser_b>
{
    std::string parse_impl() {
        return "B\n";
    }
};

template <typename Parser_T>
void print(Parser_T&& parser)  {
    std::cout << parser.parse();
}

int main() {
    using var_t = std::variant<parser_a, parser_b>;
    std::array<var_t,2> parser_list{parser_a{}, parser_b{}};

    for(auto &parser: parser_list) {
        std::visit([](auto &&arg) {
            print(arg);
        }, parser);
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, most of the times, using CRTP to access derived implementation from the base is wrong. In your case, using dynamic polymorphism would be a simpler, cleaner and more suitable way to do what you want, for both the function dispatch and the iteration.

Comment: For what it's worth: [Here is a quick example](https://godbolt.org/z/bTM5Mo4f1) of what I meant. It also makes the codebase shorter. If getting rid of the templates is an option, I would post it as an answer.

Comment: `template <typename ...P> void print_all(P&&... parsers) { (print(std::forward(<P>(parsers)), ...); }` Doesn't even require CRTP or anything, can be called with a list of arbitrary objects for which `p.parse();` is a valid expression. E.g. `print_all(parser_a{}, parser_b{});` Or actually, for which `print(p)` is a valid expression (`print` could be specialized or overloaded for a type that doesn't implement `parse()`)

Comment: @Fareanor The unique_ptr virtual poly approach is what we had before. Things is we have to create the concrete instances there anyway, and the order of sequence is the important thing. I appreciate your honest opinion that the vtable approach looks better, but I know how to do that. I don't know how to do this compile time approach better.

Comment: @Superlokkus But even with dynamic polymorphism, the sequence order is preserved. Maybe I overlooked the question but I fail to understand what was the issue with polymorphism that CRTP is supposed to have solved ?